# Moving folders in SharePoint

Tags: 2013

Is there an easy way to move entire folders to a different location in SharePoint. Specifically, is there an easy to way to move a folder up a level?
Thanks!

Comment: Use Sharepoint Designer. You can easily copy/cut paste folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using SharePoint Designer, which if you don't already have you can get from the [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491). From here you will have access to all of the files and folders on your site.

Another way to do this is to use the **Open with Explorer** feature. This can be accessed from the **Library Ribbon** at the top of the page when you are within the document library page.  This is an easy way to cut and paste folders as it uses the Windows File Explorer, which everyone should be use to and know how to use. (this feature can only be used when are are within IE. It does not work with other web browsers)

Answer (score 1):

As @Jacobcaldwell said you can easily do that, But the Point is that how will you retain the meta data associated with the file, if you want to retain.

So as an alternative, you have PowerShell scripts to achieve this.

```
    // Get your source and destination libraries
SPList source = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/SourceDocLib");
SPList destination = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/DestinationDocLib");

// Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
SPListItemCollection items = items = source.Items;

// Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);

// Now to move the files and the metadata
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{   
    //Get the file associated with the item     
    SPFile file = item.File;
    // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
    SPFile newFile = folder.Files.Add(folder.Url + "/" +file.Name, file.OpenBinary(),file.Properties,true);
    // Optionally copy across the created/modified metadata                        
    SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
    newItem["Editor"] = item["Editor"];
    newItem["Modified"] = item["Modified"];
    newItem["Author"] = item["Author"];
    newItem["Created"] = item["Created"];

    // UpdateOverwriteVersion() will preserve the metadata added above. 
    newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();                              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows explorer, in 2010/2013 it is found on the library tab of the library.